# Custom List Form: Separator line & Sub-Header/Title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, list-form

In **SharePoint Online (Office 365)**, I have a very simple and basic custom list which consists of a few columns, and I would like to lightly customize this form. So, My questions are:

**1)** How can I add a separator line on a custom list's form?  I wanna add a separator line on the form under certain field - How can I accomplish this on SharePoint Online using SharePoint Designer or JavaScript (Via ScriptEditor WP)? I am not allowed to use InfoPath nor any other third-party forms.

**2)** How can I add a sub-header/title on the middle of the custom list's form?  I wanna add a sub-header/title on the form under certain field - How can I accomplish this on SharePoint Online using SharePoint Designer or JavaScript (Via ScriptEditor WP)? I am not allowed to use InfoPath nor any other third-party forms.

Example: As you can see in the example, I just wanna add a single separator line in between the fields, and 1 sub-header.

[image: Example of List Form]

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Can you add a simple example? I have trouble understanding your goal. 

In general I would suggest JSLink as the technology to modify list forms. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745867.aspx

Comment: @Mx. I just added a screenshot example to elaborate my need. Do you have any code snippet that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Designer as alternative way to modify your list forms.

Here is a detailed guide that you can follow.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx